# c++ full screen windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need code to resize my c++ program to fullscreen.
I use Dev-C++

I tried this but it doesn't work on windows 7

```
keybd_event(VK_MENU,0x36,0,0);
keybd_event(VK_RETURN,0x1c,0,0);
keybd_event(VK_RETURN, 0x1c, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
keybd_event(VK_MENU, 0x38, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
```

Comment: For clarity, could you explain what the input faking is trying to achieve. What key press are you trying to fake?

Answer (score 2):

Don't fake keyboard input when you don't have to. Call `ShowWindow()`.

```
ShowWindow(MainWindowHandle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

Comment: It doesn't work.
"`MainWindowsHandle` undeclared (first use this function)" - in compiler.

Comment: That call will not open window in full screen mode, just will maximize it.

Comment: @David Yes, you need to supply the handle to the main window. I can't work out from here where you have stored it.

Comment: @David Do you have a handle for the window?

Comment: @Sergey I was guessing as to the true intent of the faked keyboard input.

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes, I understood the intent as well as I posted my comment.

Comment: I'm weak in C++. So, how I can do it? I need finished code to fullscreen.   
@Sergey Sirotkin - I haven't got any handles.

Comment: @David Surely you have the window handle to your main window. How did you get a window to show without having that available.

Comment: @David Sorry, I think you need to have understanding of what you are doing, at least know basic Windows API and what the window handle is. Is that a student's task?

Comment: "Is that a student's task?" yes, sth like this.

Comment: How can we give you code for your application? You said "my C++ program". Or did you get that wrong? Have you written the program at all?

Comment: "Have you written the program at all?"
No, The first think to do I need to resize window to fullscreen

Comment: No, the first thing you need to do is to create and display a window.

Comment: how I can do it? Can you give me a ready code?
I have to write a silmply c++ program with fullscreen and example text.

Comment: What function does your program call when it detects that the user pressed Alt+Enter? Call that function.